# Where would the food go if the the stomach and spleen are both taken away?

Tags: side-effects, digestion, stomach

One of my friend was diagnosed with a cyst in the spleen, and doctors said need to operate and need to take away the stomach and spleen. If this both was taken away, what will happen with the food intake, where will these go?  Where would there be side effects?

Comment: That sounds rather drastic for a cyst.

Comment: A small-bowel feeding tube can be used.

Answer (score 3):

The food normally goes from the gullet (esophagus) through the stomach (gaster) into the bowel (intestine). After the stomach removal (gastrectomy), the surgeon connects the gullet and the bowel, so the food will then go directly from the gullet into the bowel.

The spleen is not a part of the gut (gastrointestinal tract) and is not involved in the digestion of food, so its removal should not affect the digestion.

After the stomach removal, one could experience tiredness, sleepiness or diarrhea after large meals ([dumping syndrome](https://my.clevelandclinic.org/health/diseases/17377-post-gastrectomy-syndrome)), but less likely after small meals.